# Game of Life receptor

Tags: puzzle

I am looking for an interesting structure in the game of life.

If left alone, it shouldn't expand a lot(Still lifes or oscillators are allowed), but if we add an life somewhere, it launches an rocket.

Link to the Wikipedia page: [THE GAME OF LIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life)

Comment: If somebody could propose the Game of Life tag, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to combine Gosper glider guns so the gliders annihilate each other (together they would constitute an oscillator), but if another glider comes in at the right moment it creates a spaceship.

Look at the middle bottom of [this gif](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d0/Color_coded_racetrack_large_channel.gif), where three glider guns and fishhooks just oscillates until the one movement that moves along the racetrack comes along and makes a spaceship.